# Why does my displacement look jagged - Cycles?

Tags: displacement

I used this texture:
https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-spotty-discoloration-001
used the color map and then the displacement map, which I hooked up to bump node and then to normal
And this is what the displacement looks like [it's isolated with the node wrangler, to show what I mena]. The edges are blocky and jagged. Why is it so ugly? I tried Changing linear to cubic and other options. I know the color space should be non-color data, but that doesn't change anything for me. I know I can lower the bump height but that's just about it - It lowers the height but the blockyness is still there[image][image]

Comment: Your link to the displacement map doesn't produce a download opportunity unless we already have an account with Poliigon. I'd like to investigate your issue further, and follow along using your displacement map image and node tree setup, but cannot do so. Would it be possible to upload this image? Would this be a violation of some kind of terms?

Comment: Jachym - positive.

Comment: R-800 - it's a free account + free texture

Comment: I've had similar problem today. I used ColoRamp node on displacement texture and I was able to smoothen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your displacement map does not have enough information to create a smooth result. You should be using images in 16 bit per channel (or higher) and not crappy jpgs (8bit per channel compressed).

On top of that you should not use sRGB for either map, but Non-color. sRGB will distort the map information.

Additional info on the following links:

[Which color space should I use for 16-bit maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111431/which-color-space-should-i-use-for-16-bit-maps)

[Would a 16-bit image for a bump map have any advantage?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70030/would-a-16-bit-image-for-a-bump-map-have-any-advantage)

[How to get rid of the odd lines shown in the image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147242/how-to-get-rid-of-the-odd-lines-shown-in-the-image/147254#147254)

Comment: Ah, yeah! that was it - the 16 bit one was the answer - for some reason I recall Andrew Price saying that you don't have to use the 16 bit from that pack. so I thought I shouldn't use it at all for now.
Thanks and thanks for the links!

Comment: Avoid jpgs it is not a format to carry maps information.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct Displacement map hooked up to the Bump?  Looks like there are two- a regular and a 16bit.  You might have the 16bit map hooked up.

PS- you know about Node Wrangler and ctrl+shift+T right?

Comment: Yes I mentioned the node wrangler :) and no - it's not 16bit